# A little pedal newbie

Tags: electric-guitar

so i have a question, as much I search about it  i can't find any answer,it's about the distortion and overdrive pedal,soo if i have a distortion pedal and use it for rythmic parts and when its  time to solo i turn the overdrive,does the overdrive give me a boost?,does it work?or i just unleashe the chaos of feedback? (I use clean channel from the amp)
I have a distortion pedal from Behringer um 300 specifically,if it works what overdrive pedal do you suggest me? Thank you all for your patience,(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: " ...the chaos of feedback...", great name for a band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack in your question, but the key concept to understand here IMO is **compression**. Whenever you have clipping, you have compression. This is because clipping is a limiting of the dynamic range of the signal, more or less by definition.

So, when you have the distortion on you are creating a compressed signal that goes to the amp. So if you put an overdrive *in front* of the distortion (between the guitar and the distortion), then you're not likely to experience a boost in volume because the distortion pedal cannot produce any more volume only more severe clipping.

But if you put the overdrive *after* the distortion (between the  distortion and the amplifier) then it probably will work to boost the signal and maybe do some softer clipping of its own, too.

In a way there's a spectrum of different effects depending on the characteristics of the clipping. But all of these effect involve some kind of amplification component.

 `Compressor   zero to soft clipping
  Overdrive   soft to medium clipping
 Distortion   medium to hard clipping
       Fuzz   hard clipping`